# Access an instance of a component and change its value in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services, angular-dynamic-components

```
<rio-hello name="World"></rio-hello>
<rio-hello [name]="helloName"></rio-hello>
```

1. onClick of the first component I want to change the value of the
   second component
2. The value (the name) should be changed from "helloworld" to
   "myworld". Both components are loaded on the same page. How can I
   differentiate between them and change the value?
3. If both are loaded dynamically how can I  access the instance and
   change value dynamically?

Small example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iew4mn

in this dynamically loaded component not mentioned

Comment: can you share your ts file code

Comment: Please share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using e.g. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Sure i will edit on the same thanks

Comment: @coreuter thanks for your time . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iew4mn

Comment: @vimalkovath do I understand correctly: you have a list of names. To show the names you loop over the names with *ngFor and use your HelloComponent to display them. If you click on the first name, you want to change the name within your second HelloComponent? Will there always be just two instances of HelloComponent?

Comment: @coreuter ,yes exactly. So the component loaded dynamically but i want to do this first so that i can find the answer of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfq4ft) building up on your example which makes it possible to change the name of a HelloComponent by clicking on another HelloComponent

#### Explanation

In order to access different instances of a Component (HelloComponent) I used a service (HelloService) which "knows" about the existence of every HelloComponent-Instance.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class HelloService {
  helloCompoents = {}

  constructor() { }

  add(_id: number, _component: HelloComponent) {
    // store a reference to the component and use the components id as identifier
    this.helloCompoents[_id] = _component;
  }

  change(_id) {
    // here you can define the new name
    this.helloCompoents[_id].name = 'some other name'
  }

}
```

The service is quite simple. All it does is provide

1. a function to add a new HelloComponent-instance to an
   object `helloComponents` (id as key, HelloComponent-instance as
   value) and
2. a function which enables you to change the name of an
   HelloComponent-instance by using the id of the HelloComponent to
   identify the component which should be changed.

Since the service doesn't know about any HelloComponent-instances yet, we need to change the HelloComponent:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloService } from './hello.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 (click)="change()">Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() changeHelloComponentId: number;

  constructor(private helloService: HelloService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // add the current HelloComponent to the list of helloComponents within the service
    this.helloService.add(this.id, this);
  }

  change() {
    // call the change function of the service which will then change the name of the defined HelloComponent
    this.helloService.change(this.changeHelloComponentId);
  }
}
```

On creation of the HelloComponent-instance now we use HelloService to add the current instance to the helloComponents of the service.

And the click function will call the helloService.change(..) function which then changes the name.

The template of the HelloComponent now looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let list of data ">
    <hello id="{{list.id}}" name="{{ list.name }}" changeHelloComponentId="{{list.changeId}}"></hello>
</div>
```

I've added `id` which is the id of the current HelloComponent-instance and `changeHelloComponentId` which is the id of the HelloComponent-instance whos name should be changed if the current item is clicked.

Lastly you need to change your `data`-list:

```
this.data = [
      { id: 0, "name": "rio", changeId: 1 },
      { id: 1, "name": "angu" }]
```

Comment: let me check and thank you for your solution @coreuter

Comment: thank you . it works . checking for dynamic service injection . thank you for your support